# python appcfg.py update <wordpress app location> does not reflect the change on server

Tags: python, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have a local setup of wordpress.org along with a local MySQL. I completed the changes on my local that includes changing the theme and adding new posts.

When I run the "`python appcfg.py update <wordpress app location>`", I get no errors. Here's the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/google_appengine$ python appcfg.py update /home/ubuntu/shiniskitchen/
01:41 PM Application: shiniskitchen; version: wpfromstarterproject
01:41 PM Host: appengine.google.com
01:41 PM
Starting update of app: shiniskitchen, version: wpfromstarterproject
01:41 PM Getting current resource limits.
01:41 PM Scanning files on local disk.
01:41 PM Scanned 500 files.
01:41 PM Scanned 1000 files.
01:41 PM Cloning 699 static files.
01:41 PM Cloning 1161 application files.
01:41 PM Compilation starting.
01:41 PM Compilation completed.
01:41 PM Starting deployment.
01:41 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
01:41 PM Deployment successful.
01:41 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
01:41 PM Completed update of app: shiniskitchen, version: wpfromstarterproject
01:41 PM Uploading cron entries.
```

However when I try to access the public URL, I got a blank screen. The blank screen was because I had changed the theme and deleted the rest of the themes including the default one.
This is my second deployment of this app, my first deployment was with a different theme and I was able to see the changes immediately.
Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a theme.

Comment: @doublesharp, the theme is very much there. I see it in my local deployment. And I also the theme getting deployed when I do an update in verbose mode. In fact the new theme is present on the server, its just that its not activated and none of the customizations and posts are present.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Can you get to /wp-admin to select the proper theme? Or also try /wp-login.php.

Comment: Yes to both. I can select the new (and only one present) theme from /wp-admin, and can also login using /wp-login.php.

Comment: Can you try a different theme to see if that will work? You could also set `WP_DEBUG` to true in wp-config.php, if you are getting a blank screen I imagine there is an error hidden somewhere. You've checked the PHP error log?

Comment: Could not find much from it. Has anyone ever experience this? I am stuck here with my site only in my local machine.

Comment: I've experienced this, but not on AppEngine. In my case it was either that the selected theme was missing or a PHP error was being generated.